# Was there the concept of paternity leave in Spain in 1913?

Tags: social-history, spain, childbirth

I have tried to google for info but can’t find any. As the question says, I am trying to find out if there was the concept of paternity leave in Spain during 1913 and, if so, how long for?

Comment: Some context for this question might help greatly. What makes you think there might have been and why do you care?

Comment: I'd be shocked if you found an instances of it before the last few decades.  It's a very modern idea.

Comment: @BrianZ The context is a transcribed / translated civil guard note for my great-grandfather. https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39464/28260 I guess it was just a coincidence that my grandfather was born in February 1913 and then my great-grandfather was allowed sick leave for two months in June to August. So that is what nudged me to ask the question.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Yes, I thought that myself, given my own experiences with my two sons. But countries work differently and I didn't; know if there was some unofficial procedures or something ... 

Comment: When my grandparent had his son in Spain in 1935, he had to wait 8 days to get a half-day free to inscribe the birthing in the city (25 km away from his village). Now my father shows in the certificates as having been born 8 days later than the real date because in the registry they didn't care about those things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, at least not officially. Paternity leave wasn't first legislated for in **[Spain until 1980](https://www.elcorreo.com/sociedad/evolucion-del-permiso-de-paternidad-y-maternidad-en-espana-20210714135918-nt.html?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.es%2F), when fathers were given two days' leave** (or four days if the child died). In 1989, this was extended to four days and in 2007 to 15 days. Note that, historically, maternity leave evolved in large part as a response to health concerns related to childbirth (i.e. fathers didn't give birth so there was no issue here).

Paternity leave in the West was introduced in the [1970s in Scandinavian countries](http://norden.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:701827/FULLTEXT01.pdf), partly in response to the [greater number of women entering the work force](https://elpais.com/diario/2010/10/21/sociedad/1287612002_850215.html). Also, there was a [groundbreaking case in New York in 1973](https://time.com/3916437/paternity-leave-gary-ackerman/) when:

> the EEOC [Equal Employment Opportunity Commission] “found that the
> mothers-only rule ‘discriminates against male teachers as a class.’ As
> a result, the board says it will reword its bylaws to ensure equal
> rights for fathers.” That autumn, the relevant section of the Board of
> Ed bylaws was amended so that it no longer referred to an affected
> teacher as “her” or relied on the timing of the teacher’s pregnancy,
> thus expanding its relevancy to fathers and to adoptive parents. The
> determination is widely regarded as the groundbreaking first step
> toward paternity leave’s existence.

In Spain, men had very little opportunity for [paternity leave until 2007](https://www.barcelona-metropolitan.com/living/family/spain-progressive-paid-paternity-leave-leads-europe/):

> The first paternity law reforms came in 2007 via the Spanish Law on
> Gender Equality which introduced a non-transferable, two-week
> paternity leave with a 100% wage compensation, followed by other
> expansions, adjustments and improvements over the years.

Note that even [maternity leave was uncommon before the 20th century](https://www.historyofsocialsecurity.ch/risk-history/family-and-maternity). Switzerland seems to have been the first country by some distance when

> The Swiss Factory Act of 1877 provided an 8-week ‘rest period’ for
> mothers, six of which had to follow birth.

Germany also introduced a form of maternity leave before 1900 while, in Spain, maternity leave came about [in 1900](https://www.elcorreo.com/sociedad/evolucion-del-permiso-de-paternidad-y-maternidad-en-espana-20210714135918-nt.html?ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.es%2F), when three weeks of leave was granted.

---

*Note: the information on Spain comes from articles in Spanish, for which I used google translate.*

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer which helps me very much.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find anything, as the concept of paternity leave is a very modern one. I haven't heard about it before the 1980's.

My dad got half a day off to be able to register my birth at the town hall. That was all the paternity leave you got.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.